# Josephson current operator and conjugate variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, josephson-junction

I am studying multi-terminal Josephson junctions and encountered the formula
\begin{align}
\hat{I}_{\alpha} = \frac{2e}{\hbar}\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial\phi_{\alpha}}
\end{align}
where $\hat{I}_{\alpha}$ is the current through superconducting terminal $\alpha$ and $\phi_{\alpha}$ the phase (or phase difference to a reference phase) of this superconductor.
This seems a reasonable genralization of the formula
\begin{align}
\hat{I} = \frac{2e}{\hbar}\frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial\phi}
\end{align}
For a simple JJ with two superconducting terminals and one phase difference $\phi$.

This formula seems to appear quite often but I never saw a complete derivation of it. I suspect that it is due to the fact that the number of Cooper pairs $N$ and $\phi$ are conjugate variables. Then, one would have
\begin{align}
I = 2e \cdot \dot{N} = 2e\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,N] = \frac{2e}{\hbar} \frac{\partial H}{\partial \phi}\,.
\end{align}
Can anyone suggest a comprehensive explanation why this is the case ? Why are particle number and phase conjugate variables ?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day ! ;-)